# Fetching data from sqlite and storing in json

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gson, getter-setter

I have a table from which I want to fetch all data on behalf of a specific column and then want to save that data in form of JSON so that I can send it over API to the database for saving.

I am unable to get all data from the database though I tried doing it through cursor I am getting single data in this. Please help me in fetching the data and converting it into JSON. This is what I have coded. This is the method from `Dbsave` class which extends `DatabaseOpenHelper`.

```
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+"autosave",null);
    return res;
}
```

And then I am using this method in the Activity like this.

```
public void getalldata(){
  cursor=dbAutoSave.getAllData();
  if (cursor!=null) {
      if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
          for (int i = 0; i <= cursor.getCount(); i++) {
              aaa = cursor.getString(1);
              String bbb = cursor.getString(2);
              String ccc = cursor.getColumnName(3);
          }

          ArrayList<String> aaaa=new ArrayList<>();
          aaaa.add(aaa);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bbbbb"+aaaa,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      cursor.close();
  }
}
```

I am getting only one data in `aaaa`. Then I tried doing this with `gettersetter` but with no benefit.

```
private void showEmployeesFromDatabase() {
   Cursor cursorEmployees = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM autosave", null);
   if (cursorEmployees.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           // Pushing each record in the employee list
           employeeList.add(new SetterGetter(
                   cursorEmployees.getString(0),
                   cursorEmployees.getString(1),
                   cursorEmployees.getString(2)
           ));
       } while (cursorEmployees.moveToNext());
   }

   // Closing the cursor
   System.out.println("aaaaaa" + employeeList.get(1));
   cursorEmployees.close();
}
```

I am unable to parse the data from the list in `settergetter`. If I will be able to fetch all data, I will use GSON to convert it into JSON.

Comment: I can see you are printing only one element from your `employeeList`. Are you sure that you are not getting all the data from the cursor and just one?

Comment: in cursor i am getting all data as i checked the count and it was 30

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop inside `getalldata` function is faulty. It's not iterating over the cursor and just looping over the same element again and again. I would like to suggest to change the function like the following.

```
public void getalldata() {

  // Cursor is loaded with data
  cursor = dbAutoSave.getAllData();
  ArrayList<String> aaaa = new ArrayList<>();

  if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();

       do {
          aaa = cursor.getString(1);
          String bbb = cursor.getString(2);
          String ccc = cursor.getColumnName(3);

          // Add into the ArrayList here
          aaaa.add(aaa);

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());

       cursor.close();
   }
}
```

Hope that fixes your problem.

**Update**

To convert the data stored in the `ArrayList` to JSON using GSON, you need to add the library first in your `build.gradle` file. You can find a way of using it [here](https://github.com/google/gson).

Just add the following dependency in your build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
}
```

GSON takes an object for converting it to JSON. So I would like to suggest you create an object with the elements fetched from your cursor like the following.

```
public class Data {
    public String aaa;
    public String bbb;
    public String ccc;
}

public class ListOfData {
    public List<Data> dataList;
}
```

Now modify the function again like the following.

```
public void getalldata() {

  // Cursor is loaded with data
  cursor = dbAutoSave.getAllData();
  ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();

  if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();

       do {
          Data data = new Data();
          data.aaa = cursor.getString(1);
          data.bbb = cursor.getString(2);
          data.ccc = cursor.getColumnName(3);

          // Add into the ArrayList here
          dataList.add(data);

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());

       // Now create the object to be passed to GSON
       DataList listOfData = new DataList();
       listOfData.dataList = dataList;

       Gson gson = new Gson();
       String jsonInString = gson.toJson(listOfData); // Here you go! 

       cursor.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.This solved my problem.Now can you help me in converting this data in json using GSON.

Comment: I havealready accepted and upvoted it. Please if you can help me in converting it to JSON.

Comment: Great thanks! Please check the updated answer on how you need to use GSON to create a JSON String. Best of luck!

Comment: Is Data gettersetter class in this case??

Comment: No. You need to create a different class as I mentioned above. Because, as far as I can see, the `SetterGetter` class does not include a list. But in order to create a JSON string, you need a list. That is why you need an extra class `ListOfData` as I mentioned which will hold the list. I think you get the idea.

Comment: I am confused. What is the Data is in this case.Can you brief this in little detail.This is the first time i am using GSON.

Comment: So I have created two classes to store the values retrieved from the database. The first one is `Data` which stores one single value from the cursor. The second one is `ListOfData` which stores all the data in an `ArrayList`, which is used later to be passed to the GSON for parsing. Hope that clears the confusion. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Man for your support. It has been completed.

Comment: Great to know that I could help. You are most welcome. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188257/discussion-between-vipin-nu-and-reaz-murshed).

Comment: I am facing yet another problem now. data.ccc = cursor.getColumnName(3); this line gives me SELECTEDOPTION 30 times while this is name of coloumn and data there is a,b,c,d...so on. Why is it so.?

Comment: Can you please ask a different question in this regard? This answer is already too long and it is difficult for other developers to follow the answer based on this specific question. I hope you understand. You can just post the question link here so that I can take a look at it when I get some time. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your array list every time inside the cursor
Initialize it outside the cursor

```
public void getalldata(){
  cursor=dbAutoSave.getAllData();
 ArrayList<String> aaaa=new ArrayList<>();
  if (cursor!=null) {
      if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
          for (int i = 0; i <= cursor.getCount(); i++) {
              aaa = cursor.getString(1);
              String bbb = cursor.getString(2);
              String ccc = cursor.getColumnName(3);
          }


          aaaa.add(aaa);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"bbbbb"+aaaa,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
      cursor.close();
  }
}
```